# SQL split values on join PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a table called `production_cost`.

```
product     | per_day_product_cost
------------+-------------------------
powder      | 40
```

And, I have another table called `daily_production`.

```
date        | product    | type
------------+------------+----------
2018-09-09  | powder     | talcum
2018-09-09  | powder     | chilli
```

I need to fetch results from both the table which joins on `product` column.
Since the entire per day cost is `40`, I need to split the values across both the type of products, which results in

```
date        | product    | type     | cost
------------+------------+----------+--------
2018-09-09  | powder     | talcum   | 20
2018-09-09  | powder     | chilli   | 20
```

I tried case when using count and I ran out of ideas to achieve the end result. 
I am new to back end queries, so if there is any other way to do it, let me know that as well.

Comment: Is this your only use case? Or can it be 3x chilli and 2x talcum? How would you what is the amount for every single product? How do you know that in your example cost = 40 are not from 2x chilli?

Comment: @S-Man ```date```, ```product``` and ```type``` is the composite key for ```daily_production```.

Comment: And all single products always cost the same? If there were 4 ingredients then the result cost would be 10 for each? So the number of lines in `daily_production`is the divider of the `per_day_product_cost`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `COUNT` window function to get total count by `product` from `daily_production` table. then write a subquery to get each `product` total cost from `production_cost`.

```
CREATE TABLE  production_cost(
   product VARCHAR(50),
   per_day_product_cost INT
);

INSERT INTO production_cost VALUES ('powder' ,40);

CREATE TABLE daily_production(
   date   TIMESTAMP, product VARCHAR(50), type VARCHAR(50)
);



INSERT INTO daily_production VALUES ('2018-09-09', 'powder','talcum');
INSERT INTO daily_production VALUES ('2018-09-09', 'powder','chilli');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *,(
    select SUM(per_day_product_cost)  
    from production_cost pc
    WHERE pc.product = dp.product
    GROUP BY pc.product) /COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY product) as cost
FROM daily_production dp
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b0ad8/3/0)**:

```
|                 date | product |   type | cost |
|----------------------|---------|--------|------|
| 2018-09-09T00:00:00Z |  powder | talcum |   20 |
| 2018-09-09T00:00:00Z |  powder | chilli |   20 |
```

Comment: I don't have the same tables. But I do have the same structure as a sub query and not as a table. Making modifications to the answer you provided. Will let you know.

Comment: @D-Shih Why are you using the `SUM()` subselect? The table is speaking of "per day cost". Why should I sum up these values? Did I misunderstood the use case? Nice solution anyway (+1).

Comment: You probably should add the date into your PARTITION because the opener meant that the date is part of the key. If there is one date where powder is made out of some magic mystical stuff only then there would be only one ingredient with 40 cost. Or when there are two days where powder is produced with talcum and chilli then your divider would increase into 4. I think that is not expected.

Comment: see this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0ad271dc48db4192c16c812e3fe81742

Answer (score 0):

use join and sub-query

```
select t1.*,t2.cost from 
(
 select p.* from production_cost c 
 join daily_production p
 on c.product=p.product
) as t1 join 
( 
select p.product, c.per_day_product_cost/count(p.product) as cost
  from production_cost c 
   join 
 daily_production p
on c.product=p.product
group by p.product,c.per_day_product_cost
) as t2 
on t1.product=t2.product


date                    product type   cost
09/09/2018 00:00:00     powder  talcum  20
09/09/2018 00:00:00     powder  chilli  20
```

[Result demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f85c23bba07d07de9a8bc8ae7fc094a8)

Answer (score 0):

Try below with subquery for counting product type count and use then count to divide total cost of product

```
select d.date,d.product,d.type,(p.per_day_product_cost/c) as cost
from product p
inner join
(select product,count(type) as c from daily_production
group by product)a on p.product=a.product
inner join daily_production d on p.product=d.product
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    d.date, 
    d.product, 
    d.type, 
    p.per_day_product_cost/(select count(1) 
                            from daily_production d1 
                            where d1.product=d.product and d1.date=d.date) cost 
from daily_production d,production_cost p 
where d.product=p.product;
```

Comment: please change date as billing_date or anything because date is an one of the datatype

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: This works only if all single products always have exactly the same costs. If one ingredient might be gold with 100 cost and the other wood with 10 this does not work anymore. I assume that the number of ingredients per product work as divider for the whole product cost.

---

Using window function `COUNT` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=27f7d5df520de96225e7426f9e0cad5d)

```
SELECT 
    dp.*, 
    pc.per_day_product_cost / 
         count(*) OVER (PARTITION by pc.product, dp.prod_date) as cost
FROM
    daily_production dp
    JOIN production_cost pc
    ON dp.product = pc.product
```

The `COUNT` window functions groups the rows into groups. In your case a group is created for every date and product. Then it counts all rows in these groups. This result is taken as divider through your `per_day_production_cost` and is set as new column into every row.

---

Notice that "date" is a reserved word in Postgres. It would be better to rename your column. I renamed it into "prod_date".